# calling php function every x minutes

Tags: javascript

got this code:

```
<?php
function test ($url){
$starttime = microtime(true);
$valid = @fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$stoptime = microtime(true);
echo (round(($stoptime-$starttime)*1000)).' ms.';

if (!$valid) {
   echo "Status - Failure";
} else {
   echo "Status - Success";
}
}
    test('google.com');
?>
```

i want to use something like this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){<?php  test('google.com'); ?>},3000);
</script>
```

How di i call php function 'test' with setInterval?

Comment: You are conflating two seperate application domains - PHP on the server, and Javascript in the client browser. For the browser to communicate to the server you have two options - Form post, or Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You can send AJAX request to the server to execute that script after x seconds.

```
var milliSeconds = 1000; // <-- As an example
setInterval( function() {
  // <-- Your AJAX request here
}, milliSeconds);
```

Comment: @karaxuna oh yeah, it is :)

Comment: do i store the script in another file, and then for ajax request i write `xmlhttp.open("GET","script.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();` ? dont quite get this ajax request stuff..

Comment: yeah save that file separately